# Is an Android broadcast listener type API available in windows phone?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have been looking for an API that is similar to a BroadcastListener in Android. I want to listen to an incoming SMS and react to it with my app logic. Is this possible? If not exactly like this, then any other option? I did some research and found out about [SmsInterceptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.networking.networkoperators.smsinterceptor%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) API. But this is not available to use in code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an option like this available for developers at this time.

As you mentioned, the SmsInterceptor API is what you're looking for, but it's not something you can use in your code, as the ID_CAP required for this is not allowed to be used in applications submitted to the Windows Phone Store.

The SmsInterceptor API was likely added for OEMs and operators to implement in their applications, but there is no documentation on its use. Even if this were to be overcome, Microsoft automatically scans all applications submitted to the store, and will fail any application containing unsupported APIs.